# Jquery - Peticiones cada cierto tiempo, error 429

Tags: jquery, setinterval

Estoy realizando en un intervalo de tiempo verificacion para traer las notificaciones, el problema me tira el siguiente error:

```
Error :    429 (Too Many Requests)
```

**Alguien sabe como puedo prevenir esto?**

> Código actual:

```
setInterval(function(){
    refresh() 
}, 5000);

function refresh(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/notify',
        success: function(res){
            if(data != res.length){
                // console.log('actualizar!')
                data = res.length
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
                $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
                    var num = key + 1
                    mensaje += "Mensaje "+ num +": "+ value.mensaje
                });
                $('.messages').text(mensaje)
            }else{
                // console.log('no actualizar!')
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Que tal si aumentas el tiempo a 10000?
Tal vez tiene limitaciones de request tu API.
Otra cosa que podes hacer, es detectar el codigo de error, y en caso de ser 429, esperar unos segundos más.

Comment: que tal si cambias el setInterval por refrescar la pagina?

Comment: El servidor te está diciendo que cambies el intervalo. Puedes probar la opción que recomienda Lucas para reintentar en un tiempo N en el futuro (con algún elemento aleatorio)